# How to keep Python from splitting a double digit integer into two single integers, when converting to a list

Tags: python, list, sum

I was tasked with writing a script that has a user enter a list of numbers and having the script add each number in that list to get a sum. I was able to write the script, however I am having trouble when I enter an integer with more then one digit. Here is my code and working script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Sum of integers in a list

#Takes input and removes non-number characters

nList = input("please enter a list of integers separated by commas:\n")
n = ""
numList1 = list(n.join((i) for i in nList if i.isalnum())) #Converts into list of Strings
numList = list(map(int, numList1))#Converts list of strings into a list of integers
print(numList) #prints the numList

#Takes list and adds all the numbers together

def sumArg(numList):
    nSum= map(int, numList) #converts list into individual integers
    numSum = sum(i for i in nSum) #adds the integers together
    print(numSum)#prints the sum

sumArg(numList) #runs script
```

When I run the script and input (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) it prints out

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
45
```

But when I add the number 10 to the end of the list I receive this as output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 0]
46
```

I know that the sum of the numbers 1 through 10 equals 55, not 46. Is there a way for me to write this script without having Python turn 10 into 1, 0. I want to be able to have the user enter any type of integer and have it print out the correct sum.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be converting a comma-delimited string into integers like that at all. Your algorithm in particular starts the process by removing all the commas, which makes it impossible to tell one number from the next.

Instead, use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to simply split the string into a `list` on the given delimiter:

```
nList = input("please enter a list of integers separated by commas:\n")
nList = map(int, nList.split(','))
```

Additionally, you can find the sum of this `map` object (no need to turn it into a `list`) with the built-in [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function:

```
total = sum(nList)
```

Comment: Thank You! I knew my issue was at this block of code where I try to remove the non-number characters like the commas and brackets. I just did not know how to achieve that same goal without having my script split each character up.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) here.
2. I think use `return` instead of `print` is a good idea.

---

```
nList = input("please enter a list of integers separated by commas:\n")
numList = nList.split(',')

def sumArg(numList):
    nSum= map(int, numList)
    numSum = sum(nSum)
    return numSum

print(numList)    
print(sumArg(numList))
```

Demo:

```
please enter a list of integers separated by commas:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,120
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '120']
175
```

Comment: `i for i in nSum` is just `nSum`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks, didn't see that :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is your corrected code:

```
nList = input("please enter a list of integers separated by commas:\n")

# Converts into list of Strings
numList1 = nList.split(',')
print(numList1)
numList = list(map(int, numList1))
print(numList)


def sumArg(numList):
     print(sum(numList))

sumArg(numList)  # runs script
```

The problem was that your `numList1 = list(n.join((i) for i in nList if i.isalnum()))` was scanning each character. The code I posted above splits the array at each comma, turns the numbers into integers and the sums them up.

Comment: Thank You! I knew my issue was at that part of my script. I just did not know how to achieve the removal of unwanted characters without my script splitting the integers up like that.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> nList = input("please enter a list of integers separated by commas:\n")
> ```

`nList` is a string, and strings are sequences of characters

> ```
> (i) for i in nList
> ```

Here you iterate through the string processing each character individually.  You separated each character which is why "10" became "1" and "0".

Since you are entering each number separated by a comma, try splitting on comma instead.

```
numList1 = nList.split(",")
```

If the input is also surrounded by parentheses then you'll need to remove them before converting to int.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you are using Python 2, your script can be boiled down to:

```
nList = input("please enter a list of integers separated by commas:\n")
print sum(nList)
```

This is because `input`, in Python 2, already converts the input from a string into a list of integers.

---

If you want to take a string as input, and then convert it into a list of integers, you would use `raw_input` (or `input` in Python 3):

```
inputStr = raw_input("please enter a list of integers separated by commas:\n")
listOfStrs = inputStr.split(",")
listOfInts = map(int, listOfStrs)
print sum(listOfInts)
```

This expects input like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10` (without the brackets).

Comment: Pedantic: It would convert to a `tuple`, not `list`, unless the user actually entered square brackets around the inputs.

Comment: Judging by the parentheses after `print`, I'd say the OP is most likely not using Python 2.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Ah I was going by the `#!/usr/bin/python` - I thought that it would be `#!/usr/bin/python3` for Python 3?

Comment: @ShadowRanger: True, I was going by his input format (`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Probably not, or they're like me, and always lead their source code with `from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function` so they don't have to learn the Py2 special `print` statement and can use a single syntax consistently when writing for either version of Python.

Comment: @Claudiu, @TigerhawkT3: Ah, missed the shebang line. `python` would normally be Python 2, but some distros (Arch IIRC) install Python 3 as `python`.

Comment: Also, the elements in the user input pass `alnum()`, which is a `str` method but not an `int` method.